# facebook graph api search page results different with user and application access token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, restfb

I'm trying to search facebook pages with graph api's search method. I'm using restFB- a java library for facebook graph api. When i run this

```
AccessToken accessToken =
  new DefaultFacebookClient().obtainAppAccessToken(MY_APP_ID, MY_APP_SECRET);
FacebookClient facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(accessToken.getAccessToken());

Connection<Page> pageSearch = facebookClient.fetchConnection("search",Page.class,Parameter.with("q","SEARCH_QUERY"));
```

this search returns around 500 results, and returned pages are country or language depended. I mean when I run this code on a VPS on europe results were completely different.So I tried graph explorer tool like

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?locale="el_GR"&q="SEARCH_QUERY"&type=page&access_token={UserAccessToken}
```

results were Greek pages as I needed. So naturally i tried this

```
Connection<Page> pageSearch = facebookClient.fetchConnection("search",Page.class,Parameter.with("q","SEARCH_QUERY"),
Parameter.with("locale","el_GR"));
```

but no Greek pages returned.I also tried a user access token in restFB like

```
FacebookClient facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient({USER_ACCESS_TOKEN});
Connection<Page> pageSearch = facebookClient.fetchConnection("search",Page.class,Parameter.with("q","SEARCH_QUERY"),
Parameter.with("locale","el_GR"));
```

but again no Greek pages returned. If anyone can help, it would be great. Thanks

Comment: Post some code that you tried, people can't be expected to remember any API syntax on demand.

Comment: @nestedloop here are the code samples. Thanks for the reply b.t.w